# VSCode: .md is not recognize as a markdown file

Tags: markdown, visual-studio-code

I was wondering why my vs code doesn't recognize .md file as markdown file. It works well with .markdown but not with .md.

When I save the document on my computer, I can see the blue line of the markdown extension, but when I click on it and open with VSCode, it's like a .txt file and all the vscode extensions doesn't work on it.

Do you have any idea on how to fix it?

Comment: When you encounter this problem, click on the bottom right on the icon for the language (Probably something like plain Text), then go to "Configure File Association for .md Files" and choose Markdown