# vscode hold shift to insert link not working

Tags: visual-studio-code, markdown

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/markdown#_drag-and-drop-to-insert-links-and-images

I cannot get the command to inset links by dragging and dropping while holding shift to work.

Tried to debug it but VSCode simply seems to ignore the shift key being pressed.

Drag item over the MarkDown file pane, whole pane highlighted, but I do not get the help 'hold shift down' as per the docs. If I do try and then hold shift, the whole pane stays selected.

Any ideas what could be interfering and what I might be able to do to debug or fix?

Comment: This works fine for me.  Drag the markdown file into the editor, then hold shift.  You can't hold shift before you start dragging the item over the editor.  In my tests, you actually don't even need to hold shift.  You can just press it once while hovering the markdown file over the editor.  If you don't move your mouse, it will wait until you drop the file and create the link.

Comment: No I don't hold shift before and I am very please it works for you. But that doesn't really help much.

Comment: Your VSCode may not recognize .md as markdown file - see comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69839095/vscode-md-is-not-recognize-as-a-markdown-file). Alternatively, your usual Shift key may not always work (this is my case lately, and I keep forgetting :)